# How do I pause a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity with the bottom navigation menu.
I want to make it when I press the middle button on the menu, a small fragment pops up (doesn't fill the whole screen) and the rest of the screen gets a little bit darker and every touch that occurs outside of the small fragment I created will not be recognized as a touch in the other background fragment but instead will destroy the small fragment.

I created the small fragment and called detach and attach to the background fragment when I create and destroy the small one. However, it doesn't call the onPause and onResume functions in the fragments so it doesn't work. Also, I don't know how to make it that if I press outside of the fragment, it gets destroyed.
Can anyone help me?

That's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: first]
[image: second]

Comment: I would rather go with a custom `AlertDialog`. It automatically add a black/transparent background and you can set `setCancelable(false);`.

Comment: That's not what I mean, I have edited the post, see what I had in mind

Comment: Have you tried using a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?